# Self-answered: Guru Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

The Guru badge:

[image: Guru badge]

As of today this badge is not possible to achieve if you asked the question you answered.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive) and [User-badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry?tab=badges&sort=class)

Is this intended? Shouldn't any good accepted answer be awarded the badge?

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/266735) should help. It has the full criteria for all the answer badges- Other answers on that question cover the other badges. To quote the Guru part: _"Earn a score of 40 on an answer **to a question you did not ask**, and earn the accepted checkmark for that same answer"_ (Emphasis mine)

Comment: @Kendra thanks for the link. I see its intended.

Comment: Quote: "In the presence of the satguru; Knowledge flourishes (Gyana raksha); Sorrow diminishes (Dukha kshaya); Joy wells up without any reason (Sukha aavirbhava); Abundance dawns (Samriddhi); All talents manifest (Sarva samvardhan)."  I never see much sign of the last two.

Comment: @HansPassant: Not 100% what that means, to be honest?

Comment: They are the five signs of a true guru.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not very familiar with (hindu) culture/beliefs. Are you saying you disagree with this guru technicality? Or agreeing? :L

Comment: Your grumpy cynicism never ceases to make me smile whenever I see you comment, @HansPassant.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Yes, this is intentional.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/175248)

> Earn a score of 40 on an answer to a question you did not ask, and earn the accepted checkmark for that same answer

Is it *right*?  Perhaps not.  Being able to get a self-accepted answer with a score of 40 or more isn't all that common; it'd be nice to be recognized for that.

Comment: Since the 40 upvotes on a answer in it self is rare I would think its appropriate to award the badge.

Comment: Anyone can easily accept their own answer, but getting someone else to accept your answer is more difficult. It ensures that the answer actually *should be* accepted and isn't accepted just because you wrote it.

Comment: @animuson But an answer with 40 upvotes is adding as much value to the site as one which also just happens to have a checkmark.

Comment: Maybe a self-answered & self-accepted question could be awarded the Guru badge after 80 upvotes to even out difference in difficulty?

Comment: @animuson: I do see what you're saying, but to counter that, self-answers usually have a harder time getting 40 upvotes, as far as I can tell. So it's kind of swings and roundabouts here.

Comment: @Plutonix - I wouldn't think so from a search engine's point of view. Roughly estimating, 40 upvotes would mean anywhere from 4K to 400K views, some of which are almost assuredly from a search engine click-through and search engines keep track of click-throughs. There are also SEO discussions between the major search engines and high-traffic sites about elements on a page that reflect relevancy but I am not privy to those.

Comment: I got the badge from something stupid. The poster in question has put a lot more effort into the q+a combo. And from the detail in the answer, I think it's well worth a 'guru' badge

Comment: Someone could keep their answer accepted just to have this 'Guru' badge even if other answers outscored his answer multiple times, which could be harmful for people visiting question.

Comment: Congrats on the guru badge from an answer about the guru badge.

Comment: @Daniel is right - allowing self-accepted answers would give people an extra incentive to accept their own answers, even when they otherwise wouldn't.

Comment: @Daniel: There are ways to mitigate that behavior. For example, what if the self answer is the only answer on the question and has more than 40 votes (or) what if it has other answers but all others have less than half the vote count of the self answer? In those cases, would it be bad to assume that the self answer would have been accepted even if it wasn't a self answer?