# Why doesn't the badges page include or link to the full criteria?

Tags: feature-request

Someone recently [asked about the Guru requirements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296174/guru-self-anwser) and was pointed to the [Community Wiki list of all badges on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258) in the comments. A similar question about full badge requirements has come up before.

Why not add a link to the full criteria to the badges page? That way people will see that 1) the listed criteria is not complete and 2) they know where to go to get all of the requirements.

Alternatively, the Badges page could be edited so that full criteria are shown in "View More" links, similar to the [Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.